# I already know. vs I have already known

Tags: present-tense

Could you explain the difference between below sentences, please?
May be the first one is used when we talk about some common facts/knowledge, for example, "I already know a multiplication table."?

> I already know.

vs

> I have already known.

TIA

P.S. As I understand, the key word "already" very often is used in Present Perfect tense, not Present Simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, don't use "I've already known".

We tend not to use "know" in the perfect tense.  "To know" something describes a state, and not an action. So "I've known" is an odd and rather rare meaning: I have an experience of knowing something that I don't know now.  It is sometimes used of "I've known people":

> I've known people who could juggle four balls.

(I used to know them, but I'm not in touch with them now)

It isn't used of facts.  Instead you can use the verb "learn" which is the action that results in knowledge:

> I already know my multiplication table.
>
> I've already learned my multiplication table.

It's quite correct to use "already know" in this context.